# Adding hyphen in a column in sql table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help understanding how to add a hyphen to a column where the values are as follows,
8601881, 9700800,2170

The hyphen is supposed to be just before the last digit. There are multiple such values in the column and the length of numbers could be 5,6 or more but the hyphen has to be before the last digit.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

The expected output should be as follows,
860188-1,970080-0,217-0

Comment: There are many ways to accomplish this. The easiest is to use [STUFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: The better question is why you are storing multiple values in a varchar column. Your schema is the source of this problem - solve it and your goal becomes trivially simple.

Comment: @SMor, thanks for the headsup but this is what i have so far and what I need to work with

Comment: is there always a `,` before the first two?  is there any trailing whitespace?

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: Fix your data model!  You should not be storing lists of ids as strings in a string column.

Comment: @Gordon, I'm just a user of the data model and cant fix that

Comment: hahaha I was assuming each of these values was a different row. Seems that isn't the case. >.<

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select concat(substring(value, 1, len(value)-1), '-', substring(value, len(value), 1)) from data;create table data(value varchar(100));
```

Here is the full example:

```
create table data(value varchar(100));
insert into data values('6789567');
insert into data values('98765434');
insert into data values('1234567');
insert into data values('876545');
insert into data values('342365');

select concat(substring(value, 1, len(value)-1), '-', substring(value, len(value), 1)) from data;


 | (No column name) |
 | :--------------- |
 | 678956-7         |
 | 9876543-4        |
 | 123456-7         |
 | 87654-5          |
 | 34236-5          |
```

In case OP meant there can be multiple numbers in the column value here is the solution:

```
create table data1(value varchar(100));
insert into data1 values('6789567,5467474,846364');
insert into data1 values('98765434,6474644,76866,68696');
insert into data1 values('1234567,35637373');


select t.value, string_agg(concat(substring(token.value, 1, len(token.value)-1), '-', 
substring(token.value, len(token.value), 1)), ',') as result 
from data1 t cross apply string_split(value, ',') as token group by t.value;


value                        | result                          
:--------------------------- | :-------------------------------
1234567,35637373             | 123456-7,3563737-3              
6789567,5467474,846364       | 678956-7,546747-4,84636-4        
98765434,6474644,76866,68696 | 9876543-4,647464-4,7686-6,6869-6
```

Comment: Hi, actually the length of the values in the column can differ so will this work for that.

Comment: @priyesha I thought the column value is a single number. Do you mean column value is comma-separated numbers of variable length? Also, will be there be spaces before and after the comma?

Comment: @Hogan I did not ask you. I asked OP for the clarification.

Comment: @Hogan it seems only you understand the question well and everyone else here is wrong :) Anyway I'll wait for OP for the clarification.

Comment: From the question " There are multiple such values in the column"

Answer (score 1):

Using SQL SERVER 2017, you can leverage STRING_SPLIT, STUFF, & STRING_AGG to handle this fairly easily.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (val VARCHAR(100)) ;

INSERT INTO @T (val) VALUES ('8601881,9700800,2170') ;

SELECT  t.val,
        STRING_AGG(STUFF(ss.value, LEN(ss.value), 0, '-'), ',') AS Parsed
FROM  @T AS t
  CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(t.val, ',') AS ss
GROUP BY t.val ;
```

Returns

```
8601881,9700800,2170    => 860188-1,970080-0,217-0
```

STRING_SPLIT breaks them into individual values, STUFF inserts the hyphen into each individual value, STRING_AGG combines them back into a single row per original value.

Comment: The problem with this answer is it does not address the question. The question has example data with 3 values all of which much be changed. You only change one value.

Comment: @Hogan Which 3 values are you referring to?  I used the values he provided in the question.

Comment: those 3 values are not each in a row.  they are in one column.  He wants to change columns that have 3 numbers in them.

Comment: @Hogan - I've updated it to handle multiple numbers in the same row

Comment: @ Wes, the requirement is for these values and others like it in a column. So the values which I mentioned are one below the other and there are multiple other such values and the length of each value could be any different number of characters. The requirement stays the same though, add hyphen before the last digit, thank you for taking a look at this.

Comment: @priyesha - If you mean each number is its own row/record, you just use the stuff command by itself: STUFF(value, LEN(value), 0, '-')

Answer (score 0):

You can use LEN and LEFT/RIGHT method to get your desired output. Logic are given below:

Note: this will work for any length's value.

```
DECLARE @T VARCHAR(MAX) = '8601881'

SELECT LEFT(@T,LEN(@T)-1)+'-'+RIGHT(@T,1)
```

Comment: The problem with this answer is it does not address the question. The question has example data with 3 values all of which much be changed. You only change one value.

Comment: Just logic given. It can be applicable for any length of value. So where is the isuse?

Comment: Your code would give the result `8601881,9700800,217-0`  he wants `860188-1,970080-0,217-0`

Comment: Nope... Those 3 value are different. Not from a single row's column value.

Comment: "There are multiple such values in the column " -- from the question

Comment: @mkrabbani, I get an error when I try your solution, 'Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function'

Comment: can you please check the result here - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c5a157f089e549ee160ecde4f6bf434b

Answer (score 0):

If you have `"dash/hyphen"` in your data, and you have to store it in `varchar` or `nvarchar` just append N before the data.
For example:
`insert into users(id,studentId) VALUES (6,N'12345-1001-67890');`